# Fill rows with consecutive values and above rows using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
df

col1    col2
 1        A 
 3        B
 6        A
 10       C
```

I want to create a data frame from above df in such a way that, if col1 values are not consecutive, it will create another row with the next col1 value and col2 value will be the just the above value.

the data frame I am looking for should be

```
df
col1    col2
 1        A
 2        A
 3        B
 4        B
 5        B
 6        A
 7        A
 8        A
 9        A
 10       C
```

I could do it using a simple for loop, But is there any pythonic way to do it most efficiently using pandas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way using `set_index()` and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) and `ffill`:

```
df.set_index('col1').reindex(range(df.col1.min(),df.col1.max()+1)).ffill().reset_index()

#df.set_index('col1').reindex(range(df.col1.min(),df.col1.max()+1),method='ffill')\
                                                     #.reset_index()
```

---

```
   col1 col2
0     1    A
1     2    A
2     3    B
3     4    B
4     5    B
5     6    A
6     7    A
7     8    A
8     9    A
9    10    C
```

Comment: thanks, but what if the col1 contains date (the type of col1 values are numpy.datetime64), How to generate the dates in between ?

Comment: @KallolSamanta then look at `resample` or [`asfreq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) : `df.set_index('col1').asfreq('D',method='ffill')` may be or `df.set_index('col1').resample('D').ffill()`

Answer (score 3):

One way is using [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

```
(df.set_index('col1')
   .reindex(range(df.col1.iloc[0], df.col1.iloc[-1]+1))
   .ffill()
   .reset_index())

    col1 col2
0     1    A
1     2    A
2     3    B
3     4    B
4     5    B
5     6    A
6     7    A
7     8    A
8     9    A
9    10    C
```

---

Or another way using [`Series.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.repeat.html):

```
df.col2.repeat(df.col1.diff().shift(-1).fillna().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: thanks, but what if the col1 contains date (the type of col1 values are numpy.datetime64), How to generate the dates in between ?